# What are the strongest uncommon magic items?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, balance, gm-preparation

So soon enough I am going to be hosting a level 10 one-shot, and each player gets to start with 1 uncommon magic item. I want to know which ones are strong so I can look over them and make sure they won't break the session.

Comment: What problems are you concerned about? Combat? Utility? Also, almost no uncommon magic item will be too powerful or even that noticeable at 10th level, the game expects distribution of low level magic items to occur *much* earlier. No uncommon items are gamebreaking: they are uncommon.

Comment: This still likely to be closed, but it would help if you could quantify "strong". Also, a brief description of what the scenario will be like. If this is a social focused session, a Hat of Disguise could be powerful. If it's pure combat, it's pointless.

Comment: Given this only asks about a limited set of items and we all understand what strong means in general terms I find this perfectly answerable once we put down our pedant sticks

Comment: How many players, what classes?

Answer (score 2):

### None of the uncommon items is going to break the game on level 10

Your concerns are misplaced. On level 10 both the characters and their opponents have access to enough powerful features and spells that none of the items at uncommon is going to break the game.

How “strong” items are also depends on context. *Xanathar’s Guide to Everything* classifies items into minor and major items, with major being more powerful, you may want to have a look at that list (page 143, although it still is a pretty long list).

You may also be interested to take a look at [Sane Magical Item Prices](https://forums.giantitp.com/showthread.php?424243-Sane-Magic-Item-Prices), which prices items by general strength, instead of the rarity, and it also classifies items by use scenario (combat etc). In my opinion, this is much simpler and more useful than the commonality/majority approach taken in the published rules, even if the exact prices are somewhat subjective. In there, *Decanter of Endless Water, Winged Boots* and *Broom of Flying* are the highest priced uncommon items.

As case in point, the group in Chris Perkins's [Dice, Camera, Action](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a1ZbgywIF6Y&list=PLfS8QgUdeGYo8F3RPUQ2Wsi2mZLPcaU6X) did have access to two of them (*Winged Boots* and *Broom of Flying*) very early on, in tier one, and in spite of that, it was a wonderful and enjoyable campaign.

Answer (score -2):

### [Stone of Good Luck](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/4773-stone-of-good-luck-luckstone)

Is the most egregious that I know about.

However, at level 10, class features and spells are stronger than any uncommon magic item.  By a considerable margin.  You will need players that are bad at optimization for even a Rare item to be seen as strong  (something like Broom of Flying + Archer character is only 'broken' if your caster players don't know the Fly spell exists and the flying races are all banned).

Likewise, Dungeons and Dragons 5e (despite the many, many, many, many, many, many, many, many, many, many, many claims to the contrary) is not balanced.  Like... very much at all.  It has many powerful combos, many monsters with OP abilities that will wipe parties, spells that are just straight up far too strong, abilities that are literally unfair (hello Portent), etc.  If you want to run a perfectly balanced game of D&D 5e, you need to be able to read the mechanics and understand how powerful they are of every character and monster in the game - otherwise, you would do well to expect and accept some imbalance of power level.